# Start windows form application from Windows service

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have created a Windows Service in which I want to start my Windows Form application. In that application I have set the form border style to `FixedToolWindow` also when minimized it is not shown in taskbar (I have set `ShowInTaskbar` to false). So I am not getting how to start that application. When I used a simple windows form application, it starts and process is shown in TaskManager but the GUI doesn't show up.

I have written following code in `OnStart()` method to do that. Please suggest a better solution. Also why the other simple applications UI is not shown?

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"Exe path";
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
```

Where p is the object of `System.Diagnostics.Process` class.

Comment: Doomed to fail or be exceptionally awkward - services run in a different session from the (possibly multiple) user sessions. Create an application that you place in the All-Users `Startup` folder that will then run inside each user's session. Have *that* application have whatever UI is required, communicate with the service, and launch other applications, as required.

Comment: i tried setting CreateNewWindow= false also. still the dummy app is not shown.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: can you please explain in detail as this is my fist time to work with windows service. can you please post a sample code

Comment: I agree, Windows services are meant to be unattended, so why on earth would you want to start up a window from a service. Very odd.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Services do not run in the same session as the logged-in user, and this is not the way to do it.  You usually have a long running service in the background, and then either:

1. user manually starts an app which can configure the service, or
2. have a already running (tray) app, probably started when user logs in, which can be signaled by the service to wake up.

For the second case, you can use an [`EventWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.EventWaitHandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you only need to send a simple "wake up" call, or use whatever interprocess communication options you want for more complex data exchange. The latter are usually based on sockets or named pipes, either directly or through WCF, Remoting, or some other handy technology.